# Length of a $0$-dimensional interval

Tags: analysis

We defined the length of an interval $(a,b)$ as $|b-a|$.
Does that imply that the point $\{a\}$ could be wirtten as $[a,a]$ and hence the length of a is $|a-a|=0$?

Comment: In a word, _yes_. <> In more words, _we can nitpick whether, strictly speaking, those notational conventions are extensions of a definition, but they're widely-used_.